# How to pull in all elements from database in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need to put google maps markers on a map and here's the code that I'd like to use for this task:

```
  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Now this script works, but I'd like to modify it for use with an array of addresses. Can you please show me how to do it? I would get the addresses from a php SQL loop.

Comment: If your array is bigger than about 10, you will run into the quota/rate limit; much larger than that and it is better to use coordinates rather than addresses (geocode the addresses and store the coordinates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your function to accept the address as a parameter:

```
function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Then when you get the array data, loop over it and call your function.

```
var addresses; // array of address

for (index = 0; index < addresses.length; ++index) {
    codeAddress(addresses[index]);
}
```